# Add words to quotes using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have words in my String like this `word:`. I want to put it in the quotes like this: `"word":`. I tried like this:

```
new_string = re.sub(r'\n*:', '\"*\"')
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone provide this simple solution for me? I need to understand how regex working.

Comment: regex:`(\w+):` replace:`"$1":`?

Comment: @soommy12: do you have alphanumeric characters in your string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To denote beginning of string, use `^` rather than `\n` in your regexp. Also, `*` means "repeat the preceding item any number of times". Finally, to use part of the match in substitution string, enclose a part of regexp in parentheses, then use `\1` to refer to the string that matched the parenthesized part of regexp. So, `re.sub(r'^(\w+):', r'"\1":', yourstring)` should do the trick.

Comment: `^(\w+*):` isn't valid.

Comment: @soommy12 if this has no effect, there's something different between the input you provided us and the actual input you are using. Please provide us with all the information required to properly answer your question.

Comment: i removed ^ and it is ok now :)

Comment: Then apparently you have some non-word characters (spaces?) before the word in your string.

Comment: @Błotosmętek wasn't beginning of string

Comment: @Błotosmętek yeah, i just realized it was spaces

Answer (score 1):

use this. Sub will take a pattern as a first argument and replaces with a string in the second argument
In the pattern I have `(\w*):` this will match string followed by a column and keeps matched string in memory.

In the replacement string I have used `\1` which has the matched string

```
>>> s="stack: overflow:"
>>> re.sub(r'(\w*):',r'"\1":',s)
'"stack": "overflow":'
>>>
```